# How to get property value from javascript object which has dynamic property names?

Tags: javascript

I have a query created dynamically like,

```
"$select=" + selectedField + "&$orderby=" + selectedField + ""
```

This is just the dynamic part of the query where 'selectedField' is a string.
Now when I am getting my results (array of objects) and I am trying to get the values within a loop like,

```
for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
            var opt = results[i].selectedField;
}
```

`opt` is undefined. However, if the value of `selectedField` is 'new_name' and I write

```
var opt = results[i].new_name;
```

I get the desired result. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please console.log the results array?

Comment: use `console.log(results);` to see the result. Let us know about the result.

Comment: Read a few docs. You could start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors. This is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var opt = results[i][selectedField];`.

Comment: It worked :) Thanks a lot!!